# gdalinfo image.tif>stats.txt - returns empty text file (Windows 7 64 bit)

Tags: gdal, gdalinfo

I am trying to output the gdalinfo image statistics results into a text file with the following command:

```
gdalinfo image.tif>stats.txt
```

The stats.txt file gets created, however it is empty.
It does not contain any statistical information that is printed out in the command window, with the gdalinfo image.tif.

Comment: Which GDAL version are you using? It's a known issue: http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/5073 and http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/5128

Comment: GDAL 1.9.2, released 2012/10/08 - I am using this version, so in theory it should work? The links you provided are definately related, however I am not sure how to apply it. Where I should set the "Running Windows, I use a System.Diagnostics.Process to invoke GDALINFO with the STDOUT and STDERR redirected to a stream." Many thanks for your suggestions

Comment: Firstly, you could update GDAL and verify if the issue persists. FYI I have the same issue with GDAL 1.10.1, released 2013/08/26.

Comment: Had same problem in GDAL 1.11.1, released 2014/09/24. NOt sure if there is a better way, but until I need it I just renamed c:\GDALPATH\bin\gdal\plugins\gdal_ECW_JP2ECW.dll

Answer (score 3):

As I said in previous comments to the question, this is a known issue. A simple workaround consists into uninstalling the ECW extension. Furthermore, there's a (still open) [ticket](https://github.com/gisinternals/buildsystem/issues/36) on GitHub which seems to suggest a solution. Upgrading to ECW 5.0 SDK (you can find it [here](http://vbkto.dyndns.org/sdk/PackageList.aspx?file=release-1600-x64-gdal-1-10-mapserver-6-4.zip)) effectively solves this issue, however introduces others (e.g. no create method implemented for ECW format).

Comment: Many thanks afalciano! I have done 2 things, as suggested by you: (1) uninstalled ECW plugin in my 1.9 version of GDAL - the gdalinfo outputs to the text file and then (2) installed version 1.10.1 without ECW plugin. I can see from your answer there is a complete fix now with a new ECW plugin - many thanks for your help!

Comment: Don't mention it! I had the same issue in past and didn't know how to solve it, thanks to you!